# Can I use Python to transform a thermal image into a matrix to find the highest heat signature?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I've researched and did a bit of code with OpenCV, but I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish this without having to use MATLAB.

I'm trying to use Python to take in a thermal image and transform it into an array of numbers reflecting the heat signature of the the image in a grid/matrix.

For example:

[image]

I want Python to take in this image from a folder, and translate it into a matrix of thermal numbers so I can play with the max, make thresholds, etc.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What image library are you using?  OpenCV and PIL can both open images, and you can then fetch the image as a `numpy` array of pixel values.  From there, it's trivial to do your processing.  `numpy` was designed to look and feel like Matlab.

Comment: Thermal images are normally single-channel (grayscale) images with a colormap applied so that the value of each pixel corresponds to the temperature. How is that you have a full color jpeg instead?

Comment: @beaker I honestly looked up an image on Google for the example. I'm using an MLX90640 camera for the imaging, but I'm using a different laptop and forgot my flash drive.

Comment: you don't need to present us with the data but you need to *have* it. a colormapped picture is *not* data, it's a visualization for humans. -- assuming you have _data_, you're simply asking for np.max() or np.argmax()..

Comment: @ceilowens So, you're saying that there's no problem because your sensor is going to send you 768 heat values, not a jpeg image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# open image
image = Image.open('thermal_image.jpg')

# convert to numpy array
image_array = np.array(image)

# find highest heat signature
max_heat = np.amax(image_array)

# print result
print('Highest heat signature: ' + str(max_heat))
```

Comment: please review https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help as well as the [tour] and [answer]